# Change rank of records in table

Tags: c#, mysql

My table consist two fields; Code (PK), and Rank

```
Code  Rank  
A     1  
B     2  
C     3  
D     4
```

Now i want to reorder rows in my own way. I have listbox in my application where are listed
those codes. When I move up, or down item in listbox I want to save new positions in table. 
What is the best logic to do that? Any help?

Comment: how you want the result to be ?

Comment: Result depends about how user want to have order of records. I've tried with timestamp. Each time when user moves one of records it updates timestamp field and query list records by DESC. But if user want to change position of record C with B than C will be on top instead at second position where previously was record B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible I would look to create a 3rd column in the table called something like ListOrder which stored the reorder back to the database when you move them up or down.